# OSX Software Purchased (Not through App Store) not displaying as purchased

Tags: macos, mac, mac-app-store

Being a new user to Apple, I'm trying to figure out a gap in the communication between the Apple App Store and software Installed. I have two scenarios, purchased iWork 09 with physical media installed on OSX Mavericks and purchased Techsmith Snagit (5 seat license) from Manufacturer's Online Store.

When I installed iWork 09 on OSX, the Apple App Store noticed this installation and it allowed me to upgrade to the latest version. I was then able to go on to my Apple Laptop and directly download it as iWorks was now associated with my Apple ID. I didn't have to first install iWork 09.

However, with Techsmith SnagIT, on the first computer, I installed it and it is still showing the purchase price instead of *installed*. On the second computer, SnagIT does not show as purchased but just shows the price.

My question is: How can I associate the offline (not purchased through Apple App Store) purchase of SnagIT with my Apple ID so that I do not have to manually install the offline version on each machine? I would like to do this incase I lost my email and installation backup as it would be associated with my Apple ID and downloadable at any point.

Comment: Neither were purchased using the App Store. Both were available and purchased outside of the Apple App Store. However, only one of them was associated to the Apple ID on the App Store. The only difference I can think of is that iWork is an Apple Product. If that is the case, why doesn't Motion (purchased outside of the App Store) associate with my Apple ID?

Comment: I should clarify.  iWorks is sold on the Apple Store the other product is not.

Comment: Actually SnagIT is sold on the Apple Store. It cost $49.99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer:** You can't associate Techsmith Snagit with your Apple ID.

**The complete answer:**

There are two types of software (from the point of view of Apple):

Firstly, those purchased from the Apple App Store.  These are associated with your Apple ID and only require your Apple ID (and password) to be installed on other Macs.  An Apple App Store licence allows you to install the application on multiple Macs (up to 5) associated with your Apple ID.

Secondly, those not purchased from the Apple App Store.  These can not be associated with an Apple ID.  Installation on multiple Macs is usually a manual process unless you have some enterprise grade distribution software.  Licensing conditions will vary and you may or may not be permitted to install on multiple Macs.  Also it varies by product as to whether and how the license is enforced on multiple Macs.

Thirdly (did I say there were two types?), there are special cases which Apple can use for its own software.  The iWork 09 suite is a notable example.  The Apple Store software does, as you have discovered, detect this separately licensed software and offer you an upgrade (for free) to the latest visions of Pages, etc.  It also offers to upgrade trial versions of iWork 09 (but that is another story).

One of Apple's purposes (apart from making money) in creating the Apple Store was to make it simpler for users to keep track of their purchases - exactly the situation in which you find yourself.  I track mine by 'printing' all my license and purchase emails to a single folder in my Documents folder - at least they are all in one place.  You could improve on that by keeping them in a Dropbox folder so that they are available on other computers and in the event of some disaster to your Mac.

Comment: Fair enough. Kind of a shame. It would be nice for the single license type if you could install it on multiple machines, but can have only one instance open across all machines (of course this would require a constant internet connection), but would be nice.